Getting npm run dev errors trying to work with Svelte
I'm trying to work through a Svelte starter project on MDN. I was able to run the first step of the project locally after using npx but when I tried to clone the Github repo I keep getting an error on npm run dev.
I'm on a Mac running Ventura 13.6.7.
I followed the instructions for creating your first Svelte app these terminal commands got it up and running:
npx degit sveltejs/template moz-todo-svelte
cd moz-todo-svelte
npm install
npm run dev

But when I followed these instructions for downloading the rest of the project, I cloned the project, navigated to the subfolder, ran npm install and then npm run dev. It keeps generating an error:
Error: Package subpath './compiler.js' is not defined by "exports" in /Users/eskinb/moz-todo-svelte/mdn-svelte-tutorial/02-starting-our-todo-app/node_modules/svelte/package.json
    at exportsNotFound (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:304:10)
    at packageExportsResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:651:9)
    at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:592:36)
    at Function.Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:669:31)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1131:27)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:986:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1233:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/eskinb/moz-todo-svelte/mdn-svelte-tutorial/02-starting-our-todo-app/node_modules/rollup-plugin-svelte/index.js:11:4)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1358:14)

The first time I ran npm install I got a warnings and was told to do npm audit fix. The above error appeared both before and after I did the fix.
I tried removing and reinstalling node_modules in the cloned version of the project.
I tried the Mac Terminal program and the one in Visual Studio Code.
I tried updating Node.js and that did not solve it.
This StackExchange post suggested npm cache clear --force but the warning on npm cache clear scared me off forcing it.

Use the official svelte instructions instead, because as great as MDN is, one thing it's not is the right place to learn to use specific JS frameworks. With any mention of when this guide was written, and which version of Svelte it was for, you have zero guarantee that it's still applicable.

The template used here is no longer maintained and does not have a lock file (so getting version related errors is likely). As the repository states:

This repo is no longer maintained. Consider using npm init vite and selecting the svelte option or — if you want a full-fledged app framework — use SvelteKit, the official application framework for Svelte.

You could try setting up your project as outlined above, but as was already stated in a comment, I would also recommend just doing the offical tutorials.
